# Read gestures starting from a different view and ending on another

Tags: android, layout, view, gesture

I am currently trying to read gestures in my android app, which involve multiple views. I've attached an image depicting on what i want to do. I searched regarding it but the results only depicted gesture reading inside a particular view only
[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYD0B.png)

Comment: I'd look into the drag and drop apis.

Comment: Great idea Gabe! I'll look into it and update the question asap

Comment: @GabeSechan It works fine in an activity. But implementing it in an accessibilty service is not possible, since then touch input is blocked in middle part. of the screen, where layout isn't even present.